# MongoCursorTimeoutException with sort on _id

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an Mongo collection containing ~7 millions events. To get the events that happend for an aggregate I have the following PHP code

```
$client = new MongoClient();
$db = $client->selectDB('db_name');
$collection = $db->selectCollection('events');

foreach($collection->find([
   'headers.for' => '89d115f8-0b2f-470e-9495-2a07d9dfb942',
])->sort([
   'headers.occurredOn' => 1,
   '_id' => 1,
]) as $event) {
   var_dump($event);
}
```

When I run the above PHP code I get an `MongoCursorTimeoutException` after 30 seconds.

But when I run the same code without a sort on `_id`, so:

```
$client = new MongoClient();
$db = $client->selectDB('db_name');
$collection = $db->selectCollection('events');

foreach($collection->find([
   'headers.for' => '89d115f8-0b2f-470e-9495-2a07d9dfb942',
])->sort([
   'headers.occurredOn' => 1,
]) as $event) {
   var_dump($event);
}
```

The error does not occur and get instant results (which is one record).

**So why does a `MongoCursorTimeoutException` occur when a sort on `_id` is added?**

The indexes for the collection looks as follow

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "db.events"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "headers.occurredOn" : NumberLong(1),
            "_id" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "name" : "headers_occurredOn_1__id_1",
        "ns" : "db.events"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "headers.for" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "name" : "headers_for_1",
        "ns" : "db.events"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was the indexes I had.

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "headers.occurredOn" : NumberLong(1),
        "_id" : NumberLong(1)
    },
    "name" : "headers_occurredOn_1__id_1",
    "ns" : "db.events"
}
```

After I dropped this one and added the following:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "headers.occurredOn" : NumberLong(1)
    },
    "name" : "headers.occurredOn_1",
    "ns" : "db.events"
}
```

Everything went smooth